# When is memory scratch space 15 used in BPF (Berkeley Packet Filter) or tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump, wifi, bpf

My question is regarding the tcpdump command..
The command "tcpdump -i eth1  -d" list out the assembly instructions involved in the filter..
I am curious to see that no instruction is accessing M[15] (memory slot 15).

Can someone let me know , are there any filters for which this memory slot is used ?
What is it reserved for and how is it used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory slots aren't assigned to specific purposes; they're allocated dynamically by `pcap_compile()` as needed.

For most filters on most network types, `pcap_compile()`'s optimizer will remove all memory slot uses, or, at least, reduce them so that the code doesn't need 16 memory slots.

For 802.11 (native 802.11 that you see in monitor mode, not the "fake Ethernet" you get when not in monitor mode), the optimizer currently isn't used (it's designed around assumptions that don't apply to the more complicated decision making required to handle 802.11, and fixing it is a big project), so you'll see more use of memory locations.  However, you'll probably need a *very* complicated filter to use M[15] - or M[14] or M[13] or most of the lower-address memory location.

(You can also run tcpdump with the `-O` option to disable the optimizer.)